# Changing Ambient Light settings in Environment window does not affect scene after baking LightMap

Tags: unity, rendering, lighting, shadows

My settings:
Unity version - Unity 2021.1.12f1
Lightmap Lighting Mode - Bake indirect
Render Path - URP

I want to change Ambient Light in Environment window while I have baked LightMap. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you re-bake the lighting after you changed the ambient lighting setting?

Comment: @DMGregory I want change Ambient Light on Running without re-baking LightMap. Is it Possible?

Comment: ...Just what is it that you think "baking" indirect lighting means?

Comment: @DMGregory Baking with "Bake Indirect" not bake shadows from Light Source, only from Ambient Light. I was hoping that the color of the shadows from the directional light in this case can be changed without re baking. Because in this case we have dynamic shadows that updating over time. Why we can't change the color of this dunamic shadows?

Comment: I find the way to change color of shadow by using post processing. Is this the only way to do this?

Comment: Hint: the colour you see in the shadows is from the light that is *not* the direct light - ie. it's the baked indirect and ambient light showing through in places that the direct light doesn't reach. If you've found a solution to your problem, post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Coloring shadows is possible when using post-processing effects. I did not find any other options.

Comment: Your answer should walk through *how* to use post-processing effects to achieve this shadow colouring outcome. Aim to make the kind of thorough guide that you wish you'd found when first searching for help, and you can be that help for the next person who searches about this.